# Setting the tint color when using form sheet modal presentation does not work on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a UISearchBar in a modal UIViewController that has presentationStyle set to UIModalPresentationStyleFormSheet.

Setting the tint colour on the search bar is only obeyed on the iphone. The iPad still ends up using the app tint color. Any reason why this is happening?

```
  _searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
  _searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: why dont you try appearance for search bar in applicationlaunch. ex:- [[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing! Thanks @pawan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you try appearance for search bar in applicationlaunch.

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work for me. What worked was setting the UITextField appearance, but that's iOS7 only. You can also loop over the bar's subviews and change the UITextField's tintColor:

```
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```